# Eclipse: Errors in files not even in the project

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse randomly won't let me compile my project because of errors in java files that aren't even in the project.  They're part of another project I made over a week ago.

Here are the screenshots of the expanded hierarchy to show I'm not blind:

[image: hierarchy]
[image: hierarchy]
[image: hierarchy]

Here's a screenshot after going to Window > Show View > Problems:

[image]

I tried commenting out all the code in the DB class leaving only `public class DB { }` uncommented as a temporary solution, and it still throws an error saying `The declared package "" does not match the expected package RemoteSystemsTempFiles.urlToMyDirectoryOnARemoteServer`.   So I'm guessing something is up with the temp files.

Comment: The path in your problems window seems to show the files are in `MyProject/src/re...<something>` .  Are you sure you don't have a filter on in the first view that is hiding files that are actually in the project build path nd have these errors (in particular `DB.java` and `Config.java`)?

Comment: @JRichardSnape If I do have a filter, I don't know how I put it there.  How can I confirm if this is the issue? (Never worked with filters before).

Comment: In the navigator window - little down arrow on the top right of (sub)window, tool tip is `View menu`, one of items on menu is `Filters...`. Get a list of filter - check for names or types being hidden.  If it's not that, make the "path" column wider - that might tell you where the system thinks the files are and give a clue on why it's failing on them.  Usually wen I see red cross at project level, but not on individual files, it's because something has accidentally got on the project build path that I wasn't expecting.  Also - I assume you've tried `Project->Clean...`

Comment: @JRichardSnape What the...? You're a genius.  I found the filters menu and unchecked `Remote Systems File Cache` and there are the files.  Do you think it would be safe to delete the entire temporary directory structure that contains these files since they're not part of this project?

Comment: @JRichardSnape I went ahead and just deleted the remote temporary directory associated with the other project.  This Remote System Explorer plugin can really be buggy sometimes.  My app compiles and runs fine now.  Feel free to convert your comments to an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool - glad to have helped - answer imminent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in your problems window seems to show the files are in `MyProject/src/re...<something>` .

It looks like you have a filter on in the first view that is hiding files that are actually in the project build path and have these errors (in particular `DB.java` and `Config.java`)?

***To check this***

In the navigator window - little down arrow on the top right of (sub)window, tool tip is `View menu`, one of items on menu is `Filters...`.  You see a list of filters being applied to files for display - check for names or types being hidden.

***EDIT***

Following OP comments - unchecking filter on `Remote Systems File Cache` revealed the files and the compilation error was solved by deleting the remote temp directory associated with the previous project